# How can I fix the output of a GLM that only gave me "NA" in R Studio?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, glmm

I'm trying to see the isolated and combined effects of precipitation and three different human disturbances indexes are having an effect on the growth of a cactus. I have a gradient of eight different values of precipitation and eight different values of each index (livestock grazing, wood extraction, and people pressure). The problem is I only have one value of growth per each precipitation and disturbance index, so when I run the glm with this formula in R Studio:

```
growthglm<-glm(FS_POLL_CONTRIB ~ PRECIP_fs +
                GPI_fs +
                PPI_fs +
                WEI_fs + PRECIP_fs:PPI_fs +
                PRECIP_fs:GPI_fs + PRECIP_fs:WEI_fs, family = gaussian(link="identity"))
summary(growth)
```

it give me this:

```
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)      -169.80595         NA      NA       NA      
PRECIP_fs           0.26926         NA      NA       NA 
PPI_fs             24.27342         NA      NA       NA 
GPI_fs            -17.30260         NA      NA       NA 
WEI_fs             -8.59929         NA      NA       NA 
PRECIP_fs:PPI_fs   -0.03989         NA      NA       NA 
PRECIP_fs:GPI_fs    0.02980         NA      NA       NA 
PRECIP_fs:WEI_fs    0.01346         NA      NA       NA
```

How can I fix it so that the glm doesn't give me all the outputs as "NA" in R Studio? Or do you think this would be better with a generalized linear mixed-effects model (GLMM)?

Comment: as you mentioned "I only have one value of growth per each", so you get NAs for standard error.. there's no way to estimate from n=1

Comment: What other test would you recommend me to do to evaluate it?